# Plotting Related Fix Required for Initial Balance Overlay Code

Tags: pine-script

I have written a code in pine script for Initial Balance overlay. Instead of "plot", I am trying to use "line" function. But it's not plotting. How can I fix this? My code is as follows -

```
> //@version=5
indicator(title="Initial Balance New & Updated", shorttitle = "IB", overlay = true)
bartimeSess = time('D')
newbarSess = bartimeSess != bartimeSess[1]
high_ibd = ta.valuewhen(newbarSess,high,0)
low_ibd = ta.valuewhen(newbarSess,low,0)

ibh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", high_ibd, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
ibl = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", low_ibd, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
ib_delta = ibh - ibl

line.new(bar_index, ibh, bar_index, ibh, extend = extend.none, color = color.purple, style = line.style_solid, width = 1)
line.new(bar_index, ibl, bar_index, ibl, extend = extend.none, color = color.purple, style = line.style_solid, width = 1)

var table ib_analytics = table.new(position.bottom_left, 2, 6)

table.cell(ib_analytics, 0, 0, "IB Delta", bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.white)
table.cell(ib_analytics, 0, 4, "Today", bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.white)
table.cell(ib_analytics, 1, 4, str.tostring(ib_delta), bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.white)
```

I have written the code, and explained the problem I am facing, along with the solution I need.

Answer (score 0):

You pass `bar_index` to both `x1` and `x2` arguments of your line. The line starts and ends on the same bar. Therefore you don't see it.

The signature is as below:

```
line.new(x1, y1, x2, y2, xloc, extend, color, style, width) → series line
```

You need to use a different `x2` than your `x1`. Maybe `bar_index + 1`.

```
line.new(bar_index, ibh, bar_index + 1, ibh, extend = extend.none, color = color.purple, style = line.style_solid, width = 1)
line.new(bar_index, ibl, bar_index + 1, ibl, extend = extend.none, color = color.purple, style = line.style_solid, width = 1)
```

This will of course draw the lines once and the lines will stay there. If you need to modify your lines, you should use the `line.set_*` functions.